# RTextTools for coded sentences

Tags: r, text-mining

I'm new to text mining and I'm not sure if could be applied here:

I have labeled sentences but the words I work with are codes, so each word length ranges from 5 to 15 letters and there are only 4 different letters (A, B, C, D).

Looks like this :

```
Sentence1: AAABCD BAAAA ABCCBAA CCCCC...... AAAAAAABB CCCCCCCAAA (Positive labeled) ... 
Sentence10000: ACCCCCCCCCCCD ... AACCDD (Negative labeled)
```

Each sentence could be composed of a different number of words in a different order, ranging from 6 to 50 words.

Could [RTextTools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RTextTools/index.html) work in this case? When the matrix is created you have to select a language and I have no language.

Comment: This has been posted on SO and removed, which suggests you are looking for a statistical solution to your problem. It sounds, however, that some pieces of information are missing: What are you trying to do precisely?

Comment: I'm trying to find out if my sentences can be classified using RTextTools because my sentences are not in any language, they are just 4 letter codes. In the breast cancer example they classify numbers using RTextTools which makes me think that it might be used for my sentences

Comment: Thanks for the information. What do these codes represent, and why are they of different length?

Answer (score 1):

RTextTools can be used on sentences without any particular language attached to them. The package tokenizes "sentences" into words and calculates their frequencies. In this case, the words would be your strings of ABCD and the package would simply calculate those frequencies.